# PHP and ajax, prevent user calling functions in dev console

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a system for user posts and i'm using ajax to fetch data, data is being fetched once the user scrolled to the bottom of the page, so it paginates the data based on the page they're in.

My question is if there's a better, more secure way of doing this, so users can't call the JS functions through the console and possibly spam the server with useless ajax calls without actually liking a post.

This is my javascript code for sending ajax requests and saving data on client side; I save the current page, max pages and per page items in the Home object.

```
Home.all = {
loader: $("div#allLoader"),
isLoading: false,
maxPosts: 0,
likedIcon: '<i class="red-text material-icons">favorite</i>',
unLikedIcon: '<i class="red-text material-icons">favorite_border</i>',
lastLike: 0,
liked: false,
isToLoad: false,
page: parseInt($("ul#posts-all").attr('data-page')),
per_page: parseInt($("ul#posts-all").attr('data-per')),
total_pages: parseInt($("ul#posts-all").attr('data-pages')),
likePost: function (post_id) {
    var post = $('#post-' + post_id);
    var likes = parseInt(post.find('a.post-likes span').html());
    var now = $.now() / 1000;
    if(now - Home.all.lastLike > 1 && Home.all.liked) {
        Home.all.liked = false;
        Home.all.lastLike = now;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/post/like/" + post_id,
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.status === 1) {
                    post.find('a.post-likes i').remove();
                    post.find('a.post-likes').prepend(Home.all.unLikedIcon);
                    Materialize.toast('You unliked this post.', 500);
                    likes -= 1;
                } else if (data.status === 2) {
                    post.find('a.post-likes i').remove();
                    post.find('a.post-likes').prepend(Home.all.likedIcon);
                    Materialize.toast('You liked this post.', 500);
                    likes += 1;
                }
                post.find('a.post-likes span').html(likes);
            }
        });
    }
},
updatePage: function (page, per_page, total_pages) {
    Home.all.page = parseInt(page);
    Home.all.per_page = parseInt(per_page);
    Home.all.total_pages = parseInt(total_pages);
    $("ul#posts-all").attr('data-page', page);
    $("ul#posts-all").attr('data-per', per_page);
    $("ul#posts-all").attr('data-pages', total_pages);
},
getPosts: function (page, per_page) {
    if(Home.all.isToLoad) {
        Home.all.isToLoad = false;
        Home.all.loader.show();
        Home.all.isLoading = true;
        Materialize.toast('Loading posts...', 1000);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/post/all/" + parseInt(page) + "?per_page=" + parseInt(per_page),
                data: {},
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#posts-all").append(data.post_data);
                    Home.all.updatePage(page, per_page, data.total_pages);
                    Home.all.isLoading = false;
                },
                complete: function () {
                    Home.all.loader.hide();
                }
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
}};
```

That's my jquery events for liking a post and fetching posts;

```
$(document).on('scroll', function () {
    if(!Home.all.isLoading && Home.all.page != Home.all.total_pages) {
        var bottomPosts = $('#posts-all').offset().top + $('#posts-all').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight;
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= (bottomPosts) - 20) {
            Home.all.isToLoad = true;
            Home.all.getPosts(Home.all.page + 1, Home.all.per_page);
        }
    }
});

$("#posts-all").on('click', '.post a.post-likes', function ($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    Home.all.liked = true;
    var postID = parseInt($(this).parents('.post').attr('id').split('-')[1]);
    Home.all.likePost(postID);
});
```

My home.all object has a 'liked' and 'isToLoad' variables which are set to false at first, and then set to true if the user triggered those events (so scrolling to the bottom of the page sets isToLoad to true or clicking the .post-likes link sets liked to true and then based on that the ajax functions are being called to the server. I also added some server side checks to see if the post_id actually exists before adding a like to the post_likes table so users can't actually spam my database through the console with 'Home.all.liked = true' and then 'Home.all.likePost(4545454545)' with a random post id.

I'm using an MVC, here's the controller method to toggle a post like:

```
public function likePost($params) {
    $response = ['status' => 0];
    $postID = (int) Input::sanitizeInt($params['postid']);
    $userID = $this->app->currentUser()->id;
    if($this->app->post()->UserLiked($postID, $userID)) {
        $response['status'] = 1;
        $this->app->post()->removePostLike($postID, $userID);
    } else {
        $response['status'] = 2;
        $this->app->post()->addPostLike($postID, $userID);
    }
    return response($response, 200);
}
```

This is the HTML that's being generated;

```
<ul id="posts-all" data-page="1" data-per="5" data-pages="5" class="collection">
                <li id="post-5" class="post collection-item avatar">
                <img src="http://paul.dev/profile/img/default.png" alt="" class="circle">
            <span class="post-title">post</span>
    <p class="post-content">
        12312        </p>

                <a href="#" class="post-likes secondary-content">
        <i class="red-text material-icons">favorite_border</i>
    <span>1</span> likes</a>                            <p class="post-info">Posted by <a href="http://paul.dev/profile/view/AlexEY">Alex Makarov (AlexEY)</a> on Saturday 27th, July 2019 07:08 PM</p>
            <p class="post-info">Tags:
                        None
                </p>
</li>
    <li id="post-33" class="post collection-item avatar">
                <img src="http://paul.dev/profile/img/29-07-2017-01-24-03-82d02e07efaf4cf.png" alt="" class="circle">
            <span class="post-title">1</span>
    <p class="post-content">
        1        </p>

                <a href="#" class="post-likes secondary-content">
        <i class="red-text material-icons">favorite_border</i>
    <span>1</span> likes</a>                            <p class="post-info">Posted by <a href="http://paul.dev/profile/view/PauLeK">Paul Paul (PauLeK)</a> on Saturday 29th, July 2017 12:13 AM</p>
            <p class="post-info">Tags:
                        None
                </p>
</li>
    <li id="post-32" class="post collection-item avatar">
                <img src="http://paul.dev/profile/img/29-07-2017-01-24-03-82d02e07efaf4cf.png" alt="" class="circle">
            <span class="post-title">1</span>
    <p class="post-content">
        1        </p>

                <a href="#" class="post-likes secondary-content">
        <i class="red-text material-icons">favorite_border</i>
    <span>1</span> likes</a>                            <p class="post-info">Posted by <a href="http://paul.dev/profile/view/PauLeK">Paul Paul (PauLeK)</a> on Saturday 29th, July 2017 12:13 AM</p>
            <p class="post-info">Tags:
                        None
                </p>
</li>
    <li id="post-17" class="post collection-item avatar">
                <img src="http://paul.dev/profile/img/29-07-2017-01-24-03-82d02e07efaf4cf.png" alt="" class="circle">
            <span class="post-title">12312</span>
    <p class="post-content">
        23123        </p>

                <a href="#" class="post-likes secondary-content">
        <i class="red-text material-icons">favorite_border</i>
    <span>0</span> likes</a>                            <p class="post-info">Posted by <a href="http://paul.dev/profile/view/PauLeK">Paul Paul (PauLeK)</a> on Saturday 29th, July 2017 12:11 AM</p>
            <p class="post-info">Tags:
                        None
                </p>
</li>
    <li id="post-18" class="post collection-item avatar">
                <img src="http://paul.dev/profile/img/29-07-2017-01-24-03-82d02e07efaf4cf.png" alt="" class="circle">
            <span class="post-title">1123</span>
    <p class="post-content">
        sdgdfg        </p>

                <a href="#" class="post-likes secondary-content">
        <i class="red-text material-icons">favorite_border</i>
    <span>1</span> likes</a>                            <p class="post-info">Posted by <a href="http://paul.dev/profile/view/PauLeK">Paul Paul (PauLeK)</a> on Saturday 29th, July 2017 12:11 AM</p>
            <p class="post-info">Tags:
                        None
                </p>
</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Why do you think a user is going to attempt to spam your website? What's the motivation behind this? Some thoughts that come to mind: throttle requests by IP or authenticated user; return an auth token with each action that must be passed with the next request; obfuscate your JavaScript.

Comment: I think you're doing the first steps. the only other thing I would consider would be using a javascript throttling library or extension such as the one with _underscore.js and possibly a php one, like this: https://github.com/jakiestfu/Throttle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is client-side so there is no way to avoid the possibility of bot-induced spam. Anything that a user can do in a browser, a bot can automate it. You want to verify ajax requests server-side. And if you do get spam, throttle requests based on IP or some other filter.

There is no such thing as "security" client-side. It's only a matter of making things more obfuscated and complicated to automate. But is it really a good use of your time?

Comment: I've also started using webpack recently, and the plugin js uglify does a great job and mangling all the variables so users now can't even call any data from the minified bundle javascript file, but yeah I'll just add an IP throttle on the server side.